# Trying to post jmeter request using parameters but its giving me response as a Required String parameters Status Code 400

Tags: string, post, jmeter, jmx, required

I am trying to submit post request using jmeter but i am getting response as a `"{"error":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Required String parameter 'streamUrl' is not present","status":400}"`

Below is my body data

```
{
    "project": {
        "projectId": "b6d5b5c5-0f91-45b4-a602-6adc05cad978",
        "product": null,
        "organization": "7001d621-68cf-4a21-86ca-e8a6093a8bf0",
        "organizationName": "Prav_Org",
        "name": "Postman11",
        "sourceLang": "aa",
        "targetLang": "aa",
        "videoInfo": {
            "id": "10859457-c1a4-4d5b-96e2-4a24a8933281",
             "streamUrl": "https://dvy8z2ta1isia.cloudfront.net/vods3/_definst_/mp4:19761026/b46506aa-28ce-450c-ac45-d24b67e889f8.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "width": "640",
            "height": "360",
            "mimeType": "video/mp4",
            "frameRate": "25.0",
            "aspectRatio": "16:9",
            "duration": "00:02:08"
        },
        "numberOfCaptions": 0,
        "numberOfWords": 0,
        "status": "New",
        "creationDate": "2019-06-10T09:59:01.802+0000",
        "dueDate": "2019-05-08",
        "completedDate": null,
        "workflow": "4831d210-7152-4147-b77e-25ea43bd575f",
        "workflowName": "Trans+Review",
        "assignments": [
            {
                "step": "a42c73c8-a9f2-43a5-855c-e8345070cba0",
                "group": "9f676ce4-4c4e-4ee8-83ee-5d41ef52a22d",
                "user": null,
                "status": "Available"
            },
            {
                "step": "a035653e-1262-4ab9-acd5-ed96a477dc9f",
                "group": "54ad073b-41ab-4433-9bd5-465f55a840d1",
                "user": null,
                "status": null
            }
        ],
        "settings": {
            "maxCharsPerLine": 35,
            "minReadingSpeed": 0,
            "maxReadingSpeed": 26,
            "saveArea": "10% 10% 10% 10%",
            "font": "10px",
            "fontSize": 10,
            "isDropFrame": false,
            "maxSubtitleDuration": 7,
            "minSubtitleDuration": 1,
            "minCountOfFramesBetweenSubtitles": 4
        },
        "pdSettings": null
    },
    "sourceLanguage": null,
    "targetLanguage": null,
    "vttLocation": null
}
```

Comment: You are missing `streamURL` and `https` variables

Comment: @user7294900 "streamUrl": "https://dvy8z2ta1isia.cloudfront.net/vods3/_definst_/mp4:19761026/b46506aa-28ce-450c-ac45-d24b67e889f8.mp4/manifest.mpd",

able to see variables in request body

Comment: @PratikGhodsad : Its body data, perhaps you should try sending at query parameter

Comment: @Amol could you please elaborate in more about query parameters.

https://dvy8z2ta1isia.cloudfront.net/vods3/_definst_/mp4:19761026/b46506aa-28ce-450c-ac45-d24b67e889f8.mp4/manifest.mpd
The below link is generate using AWS.

Comment: @PratikGhodsad : As you mentioned, this is working from browser. Use developer console of browser, then see request made.
All the headers, request data and query parameter

Comment: @Amol 
streamUrl: https://dvy8z2ta1isia.cloudfront.net/vods3/_definst_/mp4:19761026/544bf4f2-4a05-470d-85e2-dfdfc956de0b.mp4/manifest.mpd

As you mentioned i can see this link in form data.

Comment: @Amol issue is resolved i was giving different content type as a multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBAu4mwcIYJ1EZo0G which is not required.